# rank order by group

Tags: r, grouping, rank

I tried to add a column called "ranks" in a table(outcome_4) by group(State) but the results are not correct. Could you help take a look. 
The original data table are in the following format

[image]

Here is what I wrote

```
outcome_4 <- outcome_3 %>% group_by(State) %>% mutate(ranks =order(Heart_Attack))
```

However, although I have some numbers in the ranks column , the rank number is not correct. Here is a sample of the outcome I extracted for NV. the ranks are not correct. Do you know where I need to change the code?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `order()` function, instead use the `rank()`function which was obviously made to do this:

```r
outcome_4 <- outcome_3 %>%
    group_by(State) %>%
    mutate(ranks = rank(paste0(Heart_Attack,Hospital_Name), ties.method = "average")) # this ranks on a concatenation of the two variables instead of just the numeric variable alone. Since Heart_Attack is first it ranks based on that.
```

You can use the ties method best suited to your problem, so this does look like a case for "average".

Comment: Thank you, it works. I have one followed up question. Is that possible use the rank() function on two columns for example, if the column heart attack ties, I will rank by the hospital name, alphabetically?

Comment: @brushington not natively so you would need to chain operations. I'll add an example to my code in the answer.